# How change path to my new generated webp image in index.html?

Tags: html, path, png, webpack-5, webp

I can't change the path `<img src="public/assets/images/some-image.png" />` to `<img src="dist/assets/images/some-image.webp" />` after production build.

I use this to generate `.webp` images from `.png` files:

```json
generator: [
  {
    type: 'asset',
    implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.imageminGenerate,
    options: {
      plugins: ['imagemin-webp'],
    },
  },
],
```

I also use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to create the bundle and index in the `dist` folder. My folder structure:

```bash
dist/
    index.html
    assets/
       /images
       /fonts
       ...
public/
    assets/
       /images
       /fonts
src/
    index.html
    ...
```